# How to get last message between two users?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to display last message between two users in inbox page.
But I have some troubles with selecting all users which contacts with main user(logged user).

This is my `models.py`:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    """
    Model for user messages.
    - Who
    - Whom
    - When
    - Message
    - Status
    """
    user_sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
    user_receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver")
    send_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s ->%s' % (self.send_date, self.user_sender, self.user_receiver)
```

And this is my `serializer.py`:

```
class MessagePreviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    info = UserProfileSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    last_message = serializers.SerializerMethodField('message_preview')

    def message_preview(self, obj):
        user_id = self.context.get("user_id")
        # getting last message between user_id and obj.id
        return last_msg

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'info', 'last_message')
```

And I've got this in my `views.py`:

```
contacts = Message.objects.filter(Q(user_sender_id=token.user_id) |
                                       Q(user_receiver_id=token.user_id)).values('user_receiver_id')
serializer = MessagePreviewSerializer(contacts, context={'user_id': token.user_id}, many=True)
```

So my main problem is getting list of users, which are "contacts" (have messages) with `token.user_id` and then call the `serializer` and get `lastmsg` between them and serialize this.

Is it real? If yes, what's wrong in my code?